# Method working only with .select or .reject but not working with .map solution

Tags: ruby

I have to solve the following exercise:

"Implement a first method size_splitter which takes two parameters: an array, and a integer (the size). We will assume that the array only contains words, e.g. Strings, and that the arbitrary rule is to form two groups: the first one with words of the given size (second parameter of the method), and the other group with all the other words.

The size_splitter method should return an array of two arrays - the two groups defined above - with the contents sorted alphabetically."

My solution was that:

```
def size_splitter(array, size)

  words1 = []
  words2 = []
  filtered_array = [words1, words2]

  array.map { |word| words1 << word if word.length == size }
  array.map { |word| words2 << word if word.length != size }

  return filtered_array.sort
end
```

The exercise solution is:

```
def size_splitter(array, size)
  first_subarray = array.select { |word| word.length == size }.sort
  second_subarray = array.reject { |word| word.length == size }.sort
  return [first_subarray, second_subarray]

  # OR

  # array.sort.partition { |word| word.length == size }
end
```

But i don't understand why my solution is not working, since it works on pry/irb :( can anyone help?

Comment: See [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition): `array.partition { |s| ... }` is all you need. btw, more tags is not better than fewer tags. Here the only one that is deserved is "ruby".

Comment: yes, the solution suggests .partition, but I would like to know why my solution didn't work :( btw i've changed the tags, thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorted. Then `array.partition { |s| ... }.map(&:sort)`, which is (effectively) short for `array.partition { |s| ... }.map { |a| a.sort)`. @max has identified the problem with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference between your solution and theirs, is that you are sorting `filtered_arrays` (which is an array of arrays) but you are required to sort each of the arrays inside `filtered_arrays`. You can simply change `return filtered_array.sort` to `return filtered_array.map { |array| array.sort }` or `return filtered_array.map(&:sort)`.

By the way, it's not a good practice to use `map` when you don't make use of the return value. You can replace `map` with `each` and your code will work the exact same.

Comment: The `map` function can still be used, but then it is not necessary to append within the block, i.e. `words1 = array.map { |word| word if word.length == size }.compact`. Note that `#compact` will need to be used to get rid of `nil` values produced when the condition is not satisfied in the map block. Another note: the array is being looped over twice; it could be looped over once using `#each`: `array.each { |word| word.length == size ? words1 << word : words2 << word }` This cuts the runtime in half. I would only use it if the array is quite large. For small arrays, it won't matter much.